# React "HTMLElement | null; }' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having a problem with displaying this maze grid.

What can I do to fix this?

I want there to be a 4x4 grid of divs displayed.

```
import './App.css';


function App() {

  let level1 = [
    [1, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 1, 1]
  ]

  let selectedMaze = level1;

  let maze = document.getElementById("maze");
  let player = document.getElementById("player");
  let flag = document.getElementById("flag");

  function constructMaze() {
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedMaze.length; i++) {
      let row = document.createElement("div");
      row.classList.add("row");

      for (let j = 0; j < selectedMaze[j].length; j++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        row.classList.add("cell");

        if (selectedMaze[i][j] == 0) {
          cell.classList.add("wall")
        }
        row.appendChild(cell); // if this isn't done the cell will not be added into the row classlist
      }
      maze!.appendChild(row);
    }
    return ({ maze });
  }


  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <header className="Title">
        BENJI'S MAZE GAME
      </header>

      <select id='level-select'>
        <option value='1'>Easy</option>
        <option value='2'>Medium</option>
        <option value='3'>Hard</option>
      </select>

      <div id='maze'>
        <img src="./icons/player.png" id='player' width='50px' height='50px'></img>
        <img src="./icons/flag.png" id='flag' width='50px' height='50px'></img>
      </div>

      <div>
        {constructMaze()} // errors here
      </div>
      


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried this a few different ways but am new to react. I'm expecting the 4x4 grid of divs to be returned with the other working components.

Comment: Don;t use `getElementById` in React.

Comment: Or `createElement`

Comment: What should be used instead?